# jquery set value from input type file multifile to input type file single file for multiple file upload

Tags: jquery, set

```
<form id="myForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" 
                                     onSubmit="return form_submit();">
   <input type="file"  name="myfile" id="myfile_main" />

</Form>
```

**Javascript**

```
$("#file_change").change(function(){

    var file=this.files;

    var obj=$.parseJSON(file);

    alert(JSON.stringify(this.files));

});
```

I am trying to set values from file multifile input (file_change) to a single file (myfile),

my main motive is to select multiple file and upload one by one by self.

I am getting error while setting the each value from multifile input to single file input.

I had tried $.each but not getting any idea about how to set the value in input type file (myfile).

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to programatically select files into a an `<input type="file" />`. The reason for this is security. Consider if it was possible - it would mean that unscrupulous developers could essentially steal files from visitors computers by using Javascript to select a file and submit the form without the user knowing.