# Dynamically assigning unique field name to each file uploaded via input-type="file" multiple

Tags: javascript, php, forms

The problem:

I have a form which includes a file input field with the 'multiple' attribute set.

My form handler (Tectite formmail.php) does not support the 'multiple' attribute and simply returns the last uploaded file in the array. It does this because all of the uploaded files are assigned the same input name (eg. name="img[]").

The goal:

I want users to be able to select multiple files from a single input field and have all uploaded files sent as attachments, with the form data to the target email address.

Possible solutions:

1) If I can dynamically assign a unique field name to each file in the array (eg. name="img[1]", name="img[2]", etc.) it should trick the form handler into attaching all the files.

2) If I can automatically zip the uploaded files on the client side, the form handler will simply send the zip file as an attachment along with the other form data.

I am relatively new to working with javascript and php and have searched this forum and others for answers, but have yet to find a working example.

This thread [jquery set value from input type file multifile to input type file single file for multiple file upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17162569/jquery-set-value-from-input-type-file-multifile-to-input-type-file-single-file-f) seems to indicate that changing input names dynamically is not possible.

I could find no examples on how to zip the uploaded files on the client side before submitting the form.

Any guidance would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Fixing the server would be the best solution, and less burdensome on the client.

Comment: @Pointy The server side script is not mine to alter. The script will allow for multiple file uploads if I use multiple input fields, each with a unique field name, but that IS a burden on the user. We are trying to reduce friction for the user by allowing for multiple file submissions through a single input. BTW, where in the OP did I ask if 'fixing the server would be the best solution'?

Comment: The problem is not that it has the same file input name. Having `img[]`, specifically the `[]` suffix, as the name is standard when allowing multiple files. On the sever side, it will be received as an array. With all images that were attached. If the server was not setup to receive multiple images from one input, dynamically incrementing the name will still not work.

Comment: @JM-AGMS Thank you for your reply. I agree, the form handler (formmail.php) does not support the 'multiple' attribute. What I am looking for is a client-side work around that will: 1) assign a unique field name to each image in the array, or 2) will zip the files into a single file that the server can handle. Any suggestions on how to accomplish this?

Comment: @JM-AGMS Sorry, I guess I failed to read your reply completely. It sounds like dynamically assigning unique field names will not work. Is there a way to zip the uploaded files prior to submit. This way the server will be dealing with a single zip file and should attach it without a problem.

Comment: Try uploading your images to another third-party that will return a full url to the uploaded image(s) (For example: `https://i.imgur.com/AhCz1QH.gif`), then sending those urls when the form is submitted.

Comment: @JM-AGMS Thanks again for your reply. My scripting skills are not that advanced. I was able to find a script that handles the arrayed images and sends them to a folder on my server, but I am unclear as to how to get the form to retrieve these files and send them as attachments. Are you telling me that it is possible to retrieve the files and attach them on submit?

Comment: Before going deeper into that, have you looked into this documentation?
https://www.tectite.com/fmhowto/uploading.php

Comment: @JM-AGMS I have. As you can see Tectite's script does not support HTML5's multiple attribute. If it did, I wouldn't be looking for a work around :-). Even if I set a TEMP_DIR to store the files, Tectite will only upload one. I have managed to override this limitation by including another PHP script that respects the 'multiple' attribute and will upload multiple files to the TEMP_DIR, but I can't figure out how to attach those files to the email instead. Perhaps I should be looking for a different form processing script. Any suggestions? P.S. I appreciate all the time and effort.